# How to Check either Session is Set or Not in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, session

I know how to create session in core PHP, and I have understand how to do this in codeigniter, but I am unable to understand how to check, if the session is set or not? I have tried to check this through View but it always give me the meesage `Please Login`.

Kindly tell me how can I check whether the session is Set or not Set

**Controller**

```
if ($user_type=='Student')
{
  if ($LoginData=   $this->loginmodel->studentLogin($username,$password))
  {
    foreach($LoginData as $UserId)
    {
      $currentId= $UserId->StudentId;
    }
    //[[session]]

    $data['students_data']=         $this->loginmodel->student_profile($currentId);

    $this->session->userdata('$data');

    $this->load->view('students',$data);
  }
  else
  { 
  //$data['message']= array('Invalid Username or Password');
    $this->load->view('Login');
    echo "Invalid Username or Password";
  }
}
elseif ($user_type=="Faculty")
{
  if($data['faculty_data']=$this->loginmodel->faculty_admin($username, $password))
  {
    $this->session->userdata('$data');

    $this->load->view('faculty');
  }
  else
  {
    $this->load->view('Login');
    echo "Invalid Username or Password";
  }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php 

if (!$this->session->userdata('$data'))
{
    echo "Please Login";
}
else
{

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Creating Session:

```
$newdata = array(
               'username'  => 'johndoe',
               'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
               'logged_in' => TRUE
           );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

or

```
  $this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

But before that ensure that you have the session library included.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Get Session Data:

```
if($this->session->userdata('whatever_session_name_is')){
     // do something when exist
}else{
    // do something when doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: where to write this? in view or controller?

Comment: You easily can use that on both View and Controller. But on view you need to use <?php `code` ?> that

Comment: i have written the same thing in view and it always gives me false condition message..Can u tell me where to assign `Seesion` i have declared it in `login method`

Comment: Yes Login Controller is a way to do it. But you also can use Ion_Auth library for authentication.

Comment: This is the standard way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906048/9573341

Answer (score 6):

```
 if ($this->session->userdata('variable') !== FALSE) {
  echo 'Variable is set';
} else {
  echo 'Variable is not set';
}
```

[More info](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

[Demo code](http://ericterpstra.com/2013/03/a-sample-codeigniter-application-with-login-and-session/)

Comment: where to write this? in view or a controller? –

Comment: @ravi: your tutorial is great! but I have a problem with my login/logout(let's use your demo as an example), when I logged-in then log-out and try to click the back button in browser(it is logged-in, right?), then try adding message then the bug appeared. My question is, how to deal with that problem? it's the cache that causes the bug?  but I tried this code too(clearing the cache):[LINK HERE!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071226/back-button-to-be-disable-after-logout)

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer to the question, "How to check if the session was set"

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer returns true whether it is set or set and null/0/blank. The onyl way to test whether the value has ever been set is ===FALSE

Answer (score 4):

Using has_userdata

```
    if ($this->session->has_userdata('username')) {

        return TRUE;       

    } else {

        return FALSE;     

    }
```

Comment: That's the standard way of using it. Other options are just workaround.